# SQL ordering sum two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sort the rows by sum or division two columns, like this:

```
SELECT `lastnick`, `Kills`, `Deaths`, `steamid` 
FROM `players` 
WHERE `lastlog` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - '1209600' 
ORDER BY `players`.`Kills` / `players`.`Deaths` DESC 
LIMIT 8
```

But this sql call is invalid. Is there any possibility?

Here is an example I want sort players by their K/D stat, which they played at least once in the last 14 days.

Comment: *But this sql call is invalid*: which error do you get? Please share the entire error message.

Comment: Please give the full error message. At first glance this looks fine.  *(Unrelated, why are you subtracting a string from number? Remove the quotes from around the `1209600`...)*

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be fine.  I would recommend:

- qualifying *all* columns references
- using table aliases
- taking divide-by-zero into account

So:

```
SELECT p.lastnick, p.Kills`, p.Deaths, p.steamid p
FROM pplayers p
WHERE p.lastlog >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1209600
ORDER BY p.kills / nullif(p.deaths, 0) desc
LIMIT 8
```